# Should this question be a duplicate? If not, how do I unduplicate?

Tags: discussion

I [asked a specific question](https://serverfault.com/q/502506/133416) which was marked as duplicate, but question it was a "duplicate" of didn't answer my question. What is the proper way to un-mark-as-duplicate?

Originally, the question had two sentences and the first one specified that the "duplicate" wasn't the answer I was looking for, but just to be extra clear I've added a link to that question and explained that it was **NOT** what I was trying to do. Is there something else I can do?

Comment: Hmm, I flagged the question and now it's been unmarked (and migrated to linux & unix). I guess that's the recommended procedure?

Answer (score 2):

If you feel your question was incorrectly marked as a duplicate the correct procedure is to either:

1. Edit it to make it obvious why it's not a duplicate
2. Post on Meta (which gets the community's attention and might get it reopened if they agree.
   or
3. Flag it so a moderator can look at it.

In roughly that order :-)

---

In your case the question is really an "end user" / "general Unix" question, not one related specifically to system and network administration, so I bounced it over to [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) after I reopened it.