# Please unduplicate

Tags: discussion

I posted [a question](https://serverfault.com/q/869711/276300) and it was marked as duplicate and before I could edit and explain why it's not, it was closed. I have edited it since.

I would like to reopen it, because it's basically the exact opposite of the proposed duplicate question.

So following [this answer](https://meta.serverfault.com/a/5421/276300) I'm posting on meta to get it reopened.

Comment: Since you edited the question, it was automatically put in the "reopen" queue, allowing other users with enough reputation to vote to reopen if they agree with you. I have verified that it is indeed in the queue.

Answer (score 6):

If I would "unduplicate" this, I would also close it as off-topic, maybe with a suggestion to read [this](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596100575.do) book.

The reason is that your question doesn't deal with an actual current problem you have with administering a system under your control. Instead, it largely deals with understanding how DNS (and the murky business side of it with it spammers etc.) work on a fundamental level. This is [off-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Technically, the answer linked *is* the answer to your question: No, new domain names are not advertised via DNS because that is not how DNS works and the links and comments I gave explained what happens instead.